# how to execute scientific python scripts on server

Tags: php, python, neural-network, scientific-computing

I'm working on my project in which i'm trying to classify image. for this i'm sending the image from the android device to the server for classification. On the server there is a php script that accepts the image and stores it in the uploads folder on the local server.below is the code that saves the image on server.

upload.php

```
<?php

                // Path to move uploaded files
                $target_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/uploads/';

                if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
                    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

                    try {
                        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
                        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
                            // make error flag true
                            echo json_encode(array('status'=>'fail', 'message'=>'could not move file'));
                        }

            //echo $output;
            $output = null; 
            exec('python walnut_predict.py' ,$output, $return); 
             echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success', 'message'=>$output));

                        // File successfully uploaded
                       // echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success', 'message'=>$output));
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
                        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'fail', 'message'=>$e->getMessage()));
                    }
                } else {
                    // File parameter is missing
                    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'fail', 'message'=>'Not received any file'));
                }

            /*
            $output = null; 
            exec('python walnut_predict.py' ,$output, $return); 
             echo json_encode(array('status'=>'fail', 'message'=>$output));
            //print_r($output); 
            //print_r($return) 

            */
            ?>
```

walnut_predict.py

```
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
        from keras.models import load_model
        from keras.models import Sequential
        import cv2
        import demjson
        import numpy as np
        from Tkinter import Tk
        from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
        from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator,                                
    array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
        model = Sequential()

        model = load_model('first_try_walnut.h5')
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

        img1 = cv2.imread("black.jpg")
        img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (150, 150))
        img1 = np.reshape(img1, [1, 150, 150, 3])
        classes1 = model.predict_classes(img1)

        if classes1 == 1:
            data = [{'op': 'Black Walnut'}]
            json = demjson.encode(data)
            return json
        else:
            data = [{'op': 'English Walnut'}]
            json = demjson.encode(data)
    return json


    if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run()
```

The problem is the walnut_predict.py doesn't execute when triggered from the upload.php file.

Comment: Does the webserver have the privileges to execute the python file?

Comment: how can i check if it is having the privilege?

Comment: You really shouldn't run things like DNNs in your server process. Instead you should use a job queue to decouple the two.

Comment: Any reference or example that you could provide?

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the full path to python and the script

```
exec('/full_path/python /full_path_script/walnut_predict.py' ,$output, $return);
```

Also set the script with the execution permission(+x).

Add this to the first line of the python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Finally
If you are running PHP via Apache, make sure the Apache user(www-data) has permission to access & execute the script.

Comment: Have you tried adding #!/usr/bin/env python to the python script?